# R lattice Labels for bwplots

Tags: r, lattice, label, bwplot

I would like to label some of the statistic on each box and whisker in a lattice bwplot.
A generic example below.

```
#---Some dummy data
Rock<-c("Rock1","Rock2","Rock3")
Zone<-as.data.frame(c("Zone10","Zone11","Zone12"))
Domain<-as.data.frame(c("Domain1","Domain2"))
Dt <- as.data.frame(rnorm(100))
Dt<-merge(Dt,Zone)
Dt<-merge(Dt,Rock)
Dt<-merge(Dt,Domain)
names(Dt)<-c("Data","Zone","Rock","Domain")

#--- Use aggregate to get the number of values for each combination of three factors (100 each)
aggregate(Data~Rock*Zone*Domain,Dt,FUN=length)

require(lattice)
#--- create a lattice plot and attempt to label the number of value associated with each BnW
bwplot(Rock~Data|Zone*Domain,
    data=Dt,
    xlim=c(-5,5),
       panel=function(...){
        panel.bwplot(...)
        panel.text(-4,c(1,2,3),length(x))
    }

)
```

This is not working - not sure why I'm getting labels saying 45 instead of 100. There must be a way to access things like length, mean, median and so on for each box and whisker in each panel?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to calculate the values yourself, which is easy with for example the plyr package (although you can also keep working with aggregate).

```
library(plyr)
agg=ddply(Dt,c("Zone","Rock","Domain"),summarise,length=length(Data), max=max(Data),median=median(Data))  # max or median or ... to have the xvalues were you want to plot the values of length

require(lattice)
bwplot(Rock~Data|Zone*Domain,
   data=Dt,
   xlim=c(-5,5),
   panel=function(...){
     panel.bwplot(...)
     panel.text(agg$max+1,c(1,2,3),agg$length)  # plus one to not mask the last dot
   }
   )
```

Comment: Thanks very much for your prompt solution to this question.  However, I found it did not work that well on a real data example where I had different numbers of data per box and whisker in each panel and also when there were levels with no data.  However this solution certainly pointed me in the right direction as I learned that the number labels must match the number of box and whisker plots in each panel.  By using "if(packet.number()==1) {ltext(" and so on I could set the labels to the correct position and correct sequence if I set up a set of labels for each panel.